# How to add Http request timeout?

Tags: botframework, bots, bot-framework-composer

I want to add http request timeout in bot composer so that when API takes too long to respond user can continue with the flow and request again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this currently out-of-box with Composer. You can follow a feature request thread [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/5397).

[Proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) is how you would normally handle this in a coded bot. There is another feature request to add that [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/6664).